# Spring Session with angular

Tags: java, spring, session

Im trying to config my app with spring session and angular.

I took pattern from here https://docs.spring.io/spring[...]e/html5/guides/java-rest.html

That's how my session config looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

security config:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
```

controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/products/session")
    public Map<String, String> session(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
        System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getSession().getId());
        return Collections.singletonMap("token",httpServletRequest.getSession().getId());
    }
```

and thats how am I trying to get it in Angular:

```
this.sessionService.getSessionId().subscribe(response{localStorage.setItem(response.json().token);
});
```

Some hibernate logs with different sessionId after reaching some endpoints:

```
00beba30-9d9b-418c-91ef-183eb60e876f
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.active as active2_0_, product0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.in_stock_number as in_stock5_0_, product0_.name as name6_0_, product0_.price as price7_0_, product0_.type as type8_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.type=?
820e4ada-5e52-41a7-a00a-59cafbc16a2f
4e0654e9-fa70-437f-9846-7e4671c38826
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.active as active2_0_, product0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.in_stock_number as in_stock5_0_, product0_.name as name6_0_, product0_.price as price7_0_, product0_.type as type8_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.type=?
63e06f90-f20a-4c2a-bdfc-c3fd55b9ce2e
09d0e144-26a6-4af1-ab3d-9f1378950383
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.active as active2_0_, product0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.in_stock_number as in_stock5_0_, product0_.name as name6_0_, product0_.price as price7_0_, product0_.type as type8_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.type=?
7482bc7b-7359-4870-834e-174bee2ca05b
0eeaa1bf-6a77-4d31-a295-1c95ccb9d896
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.active as active2_0_, product0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, product0_.description as descript4_0_, product0_.in_stock_number as in_stock5_0_, product0_.name as name6_0_, product0_.price as price7_0_, product0_.type as type8_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.type=?
```

so, for now the problem is that, spring session gives me everytime another session id no idea why, probably missconfig here.

If someone could help me somehow, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not related but I would always go for a session less architecture with front end and back end being 2 different projects.

Comment: I use them in same project.

Comment: I think the term "session" here is referring to authentication.

Comment: You should search a general tutorial about sessions in Java.